# Right-click -> Properties on File Explorer within Start Menu throws "File System Error"

Tags: windows-10

This is a 32-bit system that was upgraded from Vista to Windows 7, and then to Windows 10, which may be a contributing factor. When I right-click (or use the flyout menu) on either File Explorer or This PC icons, and then go to More > Properties, I get the following error:

[image: screenshot of error message]

If I navigate to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu Places, I can right-click on the File Explorer shortcut there and Properties works fine (gives me the shortcut's properties); I can also navigate within File Explorer to the top level and right-click on This PC there and choose Properties and get the System Properties dialog like I expect.

I also noticed that other than these two icons, absolutely nothing else in my Start Menu even has Properties as an option, so maybe that's related.

Is the Properties command within these Start Menu icons a vestigial option from my prior OS version, and that's why it's not working? Has anyone had this problem on a clean install? But most importantly, how can I get this command to work properly?

Comment: The error code  `-2144926975` means `E_SHELL_EXTENSION_BLOCKED` `#define E_SHELL_EXTENSION_BLOCKED           _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x80270301L)`

Comment: @magicandre1981 ...thanks? That doesn't really get me anywhere, though.

Comment: The GUID points to "System"-related property pages of properties window fail. If you installed any programs that displayed additional info on that page, uninstall them and reboot. Try running `sfc /scannow` to scan for corrupted files. Try creating a new user. If nothing works, it may be a good idea to do a clean reinstall since trying to figure out what fails is not easy, and it may not be the only problem with your system.

Comment: @JackWhite does the fact that those properties windows open just fine if requested from anywhere else besides the Start Menu contraindicate your idea?

Comment: use ShellExView to disable all 3rd party exrensions

Comment: @Dan Henderson  No it doesn't -- it is the `system` property pages that fail in your case. Go to `Start menu -> Control panel -> System and security -> System -> Advanced system settings (link on the left)` and you see the same error. `Start menu -> R-click Computer -> Properties` is just another way to open system properties window. I'm not sure about the `File Explorer` part, I don't have windows 10 nearby to test it right now; it may have displayed a different GUID number in error message. System properties window: http://media.askvg.com/articles/images/Classic_System_Properties_Window.jpg

Comment: @JackWhite actually, when I use the "Advanced system settings" link, I don't get the error. It's *only* when clicking the Properties option on context menus inside of the Start Menu. And I just verified that File Explorer gives me the exact same GUID.

Comment: That's unexpected... I have no idea what's happening, then. Sorry. Probably some kind of abnormality somewhere in the registry. If you log in as a different user the problem persists? If so, at that point I'd probably recommend to do a clean reinstall if possible, otherwise try asking on microsoft support forums. Also try searching for related errors in windows logs (`Start menu -> R-click Computer -> Manage -> Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> ... `). You could also try to follow magicandre1981's advice ( disable everything in this program: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html )

Comment: @JackWhite Thanks, I will look into those avenues.

Comment: does ShellExView help to fix it?

Comment: @magicandre1981 nope. I disabled all 3rd party extensions, and to be sure, I used the "Restart Explorer" option in ShellExView as well; still get the same error.